# Print statements no longer appear on first install -- iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, console

Something happened to my app today wherein the print statements no longer appear during the initial installation. When I first install it, the console still pops up and the app works fine, however no print statements are appearing inside of the console in Xcode. If I open the organizer however, the print statements will appear inside of there. Additionally, if I stop the app from running and then re-run it again, the print statements appear immediately. I've restarted my computer and my iOS devices but they still won't appear on first install. Side note, I just installed another app I have on my comp and the print statements still work fine on first install.

Has anyone seen this problem before or know how to fix it? I'm running Xcode 4.6 and installing on iOS 6.1.4 and 6.1.3. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
 - I changed the bundle Identifier and then the print statements appeared on the first install. However, after deleting the app and then re-installing, the print statements would not appear on first install the second time.

Comment: I have the same problem and have had it for months.  Do you know what cause it? My app never print to console on first install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem. In case anyone else reaches a similar situation, here's what I did:

1.) Changed the bundle id

2.) Deleted Application from iOS device

3.) Did a hard reset on iOS device (hold down home button and off button simultaneously for a few seconds)

4.) iOS device booted back up and the application was still there?!! (Even though I had deleted it!)

5.) Deleted app once more

6.) Did two more hard resets for good measure and now the print statements are appearing on first install